# How to display progress bar while the activity is loading? Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, progress-bar

I have some activities that onCreate function take some seconds because I have to load some data from the firebase database.
How can I display a progress bar while the activity is loading?

**Edit:**
That's my activity, I can't hide the progress bar if I set a background:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_torim);

        pb = findViewById(R.id.pb);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("backgrounds");

        try {
            setBackground();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dbreference.child(uid).child("name").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                      //some code
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        // some buttons
    }

    private void setBackground() throws IOException {
        StorageReference imageRef = mStorageRef.child("background.jpeg");

        final File localFile = File.createTempFile("Images", "jpg");
        imageRef.getFile(localFile)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                        d.setAlpha(127);
                        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        pb.clearAnimation();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle failed download
                // ...
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //some code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ProgressBar` to your layout and set it visible in `onCreate` then when you get data from Firebase Realtime Database inside  `onDataChange` make it visible with this `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

If you get data from Cloud Firestore then add the visibilty `onComplete`.

Comment: Thank you for answering.
I want to see only the progress bar while loading and after that to see the completed activity. How can I do that?

Comment: Well without seeing your layout activity I can't say a proper way but one way is to make a relative layout and have a background on it that covers everything and once data is loaded make relative layout visibility to gone.

Comment: I chose to use your first answer and I have a problem:
When I use progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);, I still see the progress bar in the background. If I don't put a background on my activity, the progress bar is hidden as well. What is the problem?
I am updating the post with code of my activity.